# Registered I/O Sockets and Tcp Window size

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock

Since Windows Registered I/O (RIO) Sockets don't have an internal buffer and SO_RCVBUF socket option doesn't apply. How is the Tcp window calculated/advertised for those?

Comment: [`RIORegisterBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh437199(v%3Dvs.85)) can set buffer size for sending and receiving. You can check if it helps.

Comment: RIORegisterBuffer only registers memory buffer with RIO subsystem so that it can be used. Specific buffer needs to be provided by calling RIOReceive and a socket can have multiple recvs pending so multiple buffers. Thats why I'm confused how is the tcp window size calculated, does it depend on total size of buffers in all pending RIOReceive calls?

Comment: @tunafish24 that would make sense, yes

Comment: @RemyLebeau so if I post more or less RioReceive calls/buffers as my program executes, then tcp window will adjust accordingly?

Comment: @tunafish24 should be easy enough to test that yourself

Answer (score 1):

[RIO API extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh997032(v%3Dws.11)) are more helpful for **large numbers of small messages** transmission scenario. It uses **queue** technique to speed up receiving and sending operations.

For multiple [`RIOReceive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_rioreceive), you can point to different sub-buffer in the registered buffer using different Offset and Length of the [`RIO_BUF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsockdef/ns-mswsockdef-rio_buf) structure.

Registered buffer will not affect the receive window size. Refer to the following documents if you want to change it.

[TCP Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level feature in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4494445/tcp-receive-auto-tuning-level-feature-in-windows)

[SIO_SET_COMPATIBILITY_MODE Control Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-set-compatibility-mode)

[SetTcpWindowSize method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/settcpwindowsize-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration)

Comment: The issue is that with normal sockets the kernel can adapt receive buffers size to the speed of the link and the load. 
With RIO we don't know  how large the buffer(s) for RIOReceive should be. 
4kb? 65kb? 2MBs? We don't want to oversubscribe nor undesubscribe.